# Ждёмс или ждём-с?

Tags: орфография, частица, словоизменение, слитно-дефис

Не нашёл ответа на Грамоте.ру. Подскажите, как правильно: ждёмс или ждём-с?

Comment: Правильно - через дефис:
https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81

Comment: Хм, по идее, должно быть в словарях. Вот только не нашёл.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Частица -с пишется через дефис, она активно употреблялась в русском языке в XIX столетии.

Согласно правилам этикета, раньше, разговаривая с людьми, полагалось добавлять к словам как проявление вежливости частицу -С.

Эта частица имела собственное название (нынче всеми забытое) – СЛОВОЕ́РС (а также СЛОВОЕ́Р, СЛОВОЕ́РИК) . До реформы орфографии 1918 года её написание было таково: СЪ.

Образование СЛОВОЕРСА связано с сокращением слов ГОСУДАРЬ, СУДАРЬ.

Последовательность сокращения была таковой: государь → сударь → су (употреблялась как постфикс: я-су пошелъ) → съ.

Произносился СЛОВОЕРС тогда, когда было уместно слово «сударь» : вместо «извольте, сударь» – «извольте-с» . Обычное место СЛОВОЕРСА – после «да» и «нет» («да-с» и «нет-с» ) , после глаголов («извольте-с» ) , а также после любого значимого слова.

Название СЛОВОЕРС происходит из системы обучения азбуке по складам, когда ученики повторяли «заклинания» в таком духе: буки-аз (старые названия букв русского алфавита) – БА, веди-аз – ВА, веди-есть – ВЕ, глаголь-есть – ГЕ. Среди таких «складов» были и с буквой Ъ (ер, еръ – по старой орфографии) на втором месте, а среди них и СЛОВО-ЕРЪ – СЪ (слово – старое название буквы С) ; произносилось последнее именно как СЛОВОЕРС.

В XX веке СЛОВОЕРС используется для стилизации, а также для подчёркивания иронии.

Comment: А есть ссылка на источник? Где посмотреть правило?

Comment: Есть в Википедии, вот Успенский "Слово о словах" http://coollingua.blogspot.ru/2010/05/blog-post_20.html